# Cant understand vbscript variable declarations

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I was tasked with converting this asp.net(vbs) application to javascript...

I'm a PHP / JS Dev and I honestly havent even read a line of visual basic code in over 15 years so I'm pretty rusty...

Can someone explain to me the whats going on here?

```
Dim VarName(100) as Double
```

It looks to me like they are casting VarName as an array, and as a double at the same time. This is confusing to me. Is it an array of doubles? or is it a double that has 100 digits?

They also do the same thing except with strings

```
Dim VarName(100) as String
```

What gives? I tried googling it all I'm getting is novice stuff that does not cover Dimming in this manner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is declaring `array` of 100 `elements` of type double, you can read more about declaring array in VB on **[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wak0wfyt.aspx)**

Different ways of declaring arrays.

```
Dim cargoWeights(10) As Double 
Dim atmospherePressures(2, 2, 4, 10) As Short 
Dim inquiriesByYearMonthDay(20)()() As Byte
```

Answer (score 0):

From VB

```
Dim VarName(100) as Double 'array of doubles with length 100
```

-> PHP

```
$VarName = array(100)
```

VB

```
Dim VarName(100) as String 'string with 100 chars
```

-> PHP

```
$name = "What is your name?" //JUST declare variable and assign it string value
```